# Passar dados de uma struct dentro da função

Tags: c, funções, struct

To fazendo um trabalho da faculdade onde tenho uma função separada que recebe dois valores (PESO e ALTURA) e retorna o IMC.

Tenho tbm uma struct chamada ALUNO onde é armazenado peso e altura e um vetor de 20 posições que irá armazena as estruturas.

O programa tem um menuzinho onde na opção 1 o usuario irá cadastrar o peso e altura, e na opção 4 eu tenho que mostrar o Nome, IMC e a condição de acordo com uma tabela que me foi passada. (A condição eu sei fazer)

Eu fiz o programa quase inteiro mas chegando na parte de calcular o IMC não consigo passar a struct dentro da função. Eu sei que tem como passar por valor ou referencia mas já tentei e não consigo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Agradeço desde já!

```
//DECLARANDO ESTRUTURA 
struct aluno {

    char nome[100];
    char email[100];
    float altura;
    float peso;
};

//VETOR 
struct aluno info[21];


//FUNÇÃO SEPARADA DE IMC
float calculaImc(float altura, peso) {


    float resultado;

    resultado = peso / (altura*altura);
    return resultado;
}

//FUNÇÃO PRICIPAL
int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    //DECLARANDO OUTRAS VARIAVEIS NECESSARIAS
    int i, op, posicao, excluir;

    do{

        system("cls");
        printf("\nCADASTRANDO ALUNOS NA ACADEMIA\n");
        printf("\n\t MENU \n");
        printf("\n1. Cadastrar aluno.\n");
        printf("2. Listar alunos.\n");
        printf("3. Apagar aluno.\n");
        printf("4. Listar IMC de alunos.\n");
        printf("0. Sair.\n");

        printf("\nEscolha uma das opções do menu: ");
        scanf("%i", &op);
        printf("\n");

        switch(op) {

            case(1):

                printf("Posições que já possuem cadastro: ");
                for(i=0; i<21; i++) {
                    if (info[i].nome[0] == '\0'){ 
                        continue;                 
                    }
                    printf("%d " , i);
                }

                printf("\nEscolha de 1 a 20: ");
                scanf("%d", &posicao);
                i=posicao;

                if(posicao > 20){
                    printf("\nVocê digitou um valor invalido, tente novamente!\n");
                }else{

                    printf("\n Posição escolhida: %d. \n", i);
                    printf("\n");

                    printf("Nome : ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    gets(info[i].nome);

                    printf("Email : ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    gets(info[i].email);

                    printf("Altura (m): ");
                    scanf("%f", &info[i].altura);
                    fflush(stdin);

                    printf("Peso (kg): ");
                    scanf("%f", &info[i].peso);
                    fflush(stdin);

                    if(info[i].nome[0] == '\0') {
                        printf("\nErro. Você não colocou um Nome.\n");
                    }else{
                    printf("\nAluno cadastrado com sucesso!\n");
                    }
                }
                break;

            case(2):

                printf("Alunos cadastrados.\n");

                for(i=0; i<21 ; i++){
                    if (info[i].nome[0] == '\0'){
                        continue;
                    }
                    printf("\nAluno %d \n", i);
                    printf("Nome: %s \n" , info[i].nome);
                    printf("Email: %s \n" , info[i].email);
                    printf("Altura: %.2f m \n", info[i].altura);
                    printf("Peso: %.2f kg \n", info[i].peso);
                }

                break;

            case(3):

                printf("Apagar aluno: ");
                scanf("%d", &excluir);

                if(info[excluir].nome[0] != '\0') {
                    printf("\nEssa posição corresponde ao seguinte aluno: %s.\n", info[excluir].nome);

                break;

            case(4):
                for(i=0; i<21; i++) {
                    if (info[i].nome[0] == '\0'){ 
                        continue;               
                    }
                    printf("\nAluno %d \n", i);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", info[i].nome);
                }

                break;
        }

    }while(op!=0);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que você precisa passar a *struct* para a função do IMC? Não pode passar apenas o peso e a altura e receber o resultado da função  na *main*?

Comment: Acho que poderia ser tmb, mas fiz como o Isac falou e deu certinho. Obrigado msm assim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mais normal seria passar um ponteiro para a estrutura que quer aceder na função, e em muitos casos será mais eficiente pois evita copiar conteúdo desnecessariamente.

A função ficaria assim:

```
//FUNÇÃO SEPARADA QUE RECEBE PESO E ALTURA E RETORNA O IMC
float calculaImc(struct aluno *al) {
//                            ^--- Tipo ponteiro para struct aluno
    float resultado;

    resultado = al->peso / (al->altura * al->altura);
    //            ^-----------^------------^-- acede com ponteiro -> campo
    return resultado;
}
```

E a chamada à função do `main` seria:

```
calculaImc(&info[i]);
```

Repare que coloquei `&info[i]`, pois o `&` acede à posição na memória do elemento. Isto é necessário porque a função recebe um ponteiro, ou seja, o local em memória onde está a estrutura.

Encaixando no seu `case 4` ficaria:

```
case(4):
    for(i=0; i<21; i++) {
        if (info[i].nome[0] == '\0'){ //SE A PRIMEIRA POSIÇÃO DA STRING FOR IGUAL A \0
            continue;                 //ENTÃO PULA PARA O PROXIMO
        }
        printf("\nAluno %d \n", i);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", info[i].nome);
        printf("IMC: %f\n", calculaImc(&info[i])); //<--imc aqui com & para ser o ponteiro
    }
```

Recomendações:

- Evite utilizar a função `getch`, pois ele é especifica de windows o que faz com que o seu programa seja menos portável.
- Não misture `gets` com `scanf`. Melhor ainda, não use `gets` de todo, pois é uma função perigosa e suscetível a ataques de *buffer overflow*. Para além disso utilizar as duas cria problemas de passagens de uma para outra com o que fica no *buffer* de entrada. Isto foi o que lhe levou a utilizar vários `fflush(stdin)`, que não só não são o ideal, como nem sequer é garantido que todas as implementações limpem de facto os *buffers* com essa chamada.

Nota:

Na declaração da função `calculaImc` que tem na pergunta, ficou a faltar o tipo para o parâmetro `peso`:

```
float calculaImc(float altura, peso) {
//                            ^---- aqui
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu certinho!!!!!! Em relação a essas dicas vou tentar colocar em pratica. Eu vi msm que é melhor usar fgets porem não tava conseguindo implementar no meu código.